# Creating an update function within my display class in Python

Tags: class, python-2.7, object, pygame

So I am trying to code it when I call my myDisplay.update() function I can pass whatever game element I want to update into it, to display the image. For example I made a player with a player class, and I want to pass it into myDisplay.update(player), to pull the sprite from the player class and then render it in the update method.

Current Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Display' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

Current Code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#Constants
TILESIZE = 32
MAPWIDTH = 16
MAPHEIGHT = 16

#variables
playing = True

#Creates Display Window
class Display(object):

    def __init__(self, width, height, tilesize):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("FarmTown Version 1.0")
        self.SCREEN_WIDTH = width * tilesize
        self.SCREEN_HEIGHT = height * tilesize
        self.myScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([self.SCREEN_WIDTH, self.SCREEN_HEIGHT])

    def update(self, updated):
        self.blit(updated.image, (playerPos[0] * TILESIZE, playerPos[1] * TILESIZE))
        pygame.display.update()

class Controller(object):
    controls = {
        "KEY_UP": 273,
        "KEY_DOWN": 274,
        "KEY_RIGHT": 275,
        "KEY_LEFT": 276
        }

    def checkInput(self):
        for key in self.controls:
            if event.key == self.controls[key]:
                if self.controls[key] == self.controls["KEY_UP"]:
                    print "Up"
                elif self.controls[key] == self.controls["KEY_DOWN"]:
                    print "Down"
                elif self.controls[key] == self.controls["KEY_RIGHT"]:
                    print "Right"
                elif self.controls[key] == self.controls["KEY_LEFT"]:
                    print "Left"

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #if playerClass == "peasant":
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png")
        self.pos = [0, 0]

#Set Up Everything To Play
myDisplay = Display(MAPWIDTH, MAPHEIGHT, TILESIZE)
myController = Controller()
player = Player()


#Game Loop Begins
while playing:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            myController.checkInput()

    myDisplay.update(player)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to subclass a pygame object. Currently Display is a subclass of just "object", which doesn't contain the "blit" method. Or did you mean to write `pygame.blit` or `pygame.display.blit` instead of `self.blit`?

Comment: I'm currently still running through my code, and noticed that I think I should be using self.myScreen.blit as during the __init__ I did create the myScreen variable, does this sound like something that might be on the correct path? I am trying to use the pygame blit function, but I've only ever used it after creating the main window/surface. This was the original tutorial I learned my bliting from. They use DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((ect.)) and then access everything from DISPLAYSURF

Comment: I don't actually know pygame, but it looks like `blit` is a method of Screen objects, so what you're saying looks exactly right.

When I use a new framework, I like to start by basing some code closely on an example. Have you looked at the examples in the pygame documentation? https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/tom/games2.html